# AngularJs - How to use timezone into datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, timezone, datetimepicker

I am using the angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker directive (https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                       date-parser="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" name="dataInicial"
                       ng-model="myModel"
                       ui-date-time-mask required>
            </div>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <datetimepicker data-ng-model="mymodel" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownDataInicial', minuteStep: 1 }"/>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and I would like to use timezone for formatting. How do I do that ?

Can someone help me, please ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to display the timezone from the ng-model, or do you need to set the timezone?

Comment: I need to set the timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use moment to set the time zone. For example, when initializing your application you can call `moment.tz.setDefault('America/Los_Angeles');` (passing in your desired time zone) and moment should take care of the rest.